# How to install phpunit under OSX 10.8.4 with MAMP 2.1.4 for Yii and Netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans, yii, phpunit, mamp

I want use phpunit tests on my local maschine running OSX 10.8.4 and MAMP Pro with PHP 5.4.1. Further I want use it for Yii and my IDE Netbeans.

I read a few tutorials like this approach via [pear](http://jeffreybarke.net/2010/08/how-to-install-phpunit-with-mamp/) or this one via [composer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15850032/931358). I even tried to look like ppl do it on [windows](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/14995-wamp-netbeans-phpunit-selenium-yii/) - without success.

My approaches always resulted in errors like

> PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'PHP_Invoker.php'
>
> PHP Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase.php'
>
> PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening
>   'PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase.php'
>
> Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php'
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CTestCase' not found

or phpunit wasn't found at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But finally I found a tutorial that gave me a good start. And with a little bit more research, I found solutions for the problems I posted above too.

Here I just want share my steps and all the links you can go thru to get it run :)

**First step** is to follow [Zank's tutorial](http://imzank.com/2012/08/how-to-install-phpunit-with-mamp/).

But after I did his steps, I got several errors. Because the list of modules you have to install is not complete. This ended up in following errors when I tried to run a test:

> PHP Warning: include(): Failed opening 'PHP_Invoker.php'
>
> PHP Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase.php'
>
> PHP Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'PHPUnit_Extensions_Story_TestCase.php'

**Second step**

So I googled and figured out that I have to do following lines too:

```
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_Story

pear install phpunit/DbUnit
```

But the 'invoker' problem was not that easy. Because when you try

```
pear install phpunit/PHP_Invoker
```

it will result in an error like

> phpunit/PHP_Invoker requires PHP extension "pcntl"

and to install this extension to MAMP is a pain in the ass. But I [found](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/1907#issuecomment-14519537) here this solution:

> - went to pear.phpunit.de
> - manually downloaded PHP_Invoker utility class
> - unzipped the file on my daughter's mac (I'm running Windows)
> - put the "Invoker" directory under C:\xampp\php\pear\PHP
> - put the "Invoker.php" file under C:\xampp\php\pear\PHP

For your MAMP installation the path should be something like "**/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib**" - further I had to rename 'Invoker.php' to 'PHP_Invoker.php'.

**Step Three**

On command line everything should work now - write a test and try it out like in Zank's tutorial linked in step one. But what about Netbeans? Like in Zank's tutorial I entered the phpunit path and just right clicked one of my tests and selected "Run test" - error!

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CTestCase' not found

Solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241194/php-fatal-error-class-ctestcase-not-found-in). This happens when you do not right click the folder where the 'phpunit.xml' is in. But to avoid this you could do the following:

- Only right click the folder with the 'phpunit.xml' in it for 'Run test'.
- Or go under your test properties -> PHPUnit and check the checkbox 'Use XML Configuration' + select the 'phpunit.xml' file

That's it!

Here are some links that are interessting too:

- [NetBeans IDE - Testing with PHPUnit and Selenium](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html)
- [NetBeans IDE and Yii projects](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/83/)
- [NetBeans IDE, PHPUnit and Skeleton Generator](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/skeleton-generator.html)